# How to resolve "HTTP Status 404: The origin server did not find a current representation..." error while running Javax servlet on Tomcat server?

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404, tomcat7

I am trying to run Plutext's docx-html-editor. When I deploy the war file on Tomcat server, it renders the index.html, but when it submits form and redirects to another page, it shows "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists." error.

I have tried changing versions of maven plugins, replacing javax servlet with latest jakarta servlet.

Build configuration in pom.xml:
[image]

Servelt configuration in Web.xml:
[image]

Comment: After checking logs, I found out I was using Tomcat 10 and the existing dependencies were not compatible with Tomcat 10. I downgraded it to 8 and it worked fine.